# How to distinguish a question more appropriate for Biology-SE or CogSci-SE or Health-SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Recently going through [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56185/why-do-we-fear-more-in-the-night) question (that has been put hold as off-topic; and commented for more appropriate to CogSci.SE) ; to me it looked highly like a biology (physiology) question such as [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50744/why-do-we-feel-sleepy-when-we-wake-up) sleep-wake cycle question.

So it seems the border between Biology, Cognitive-science and Health(or medical-science); is very much blurry, interrelated as well as quite subjective.

So; do-we have some principle to technically/ officially consider a question as biology or cog-sci or health?

Comment: The first question is more or less opinion-based unless more background is provided. Certainly it is possible that diurnal animals are afraid of dark because many predators are nocturnal. The question does not delve into the evolutionary aspects and is more about a personal experience.

Comment: The second question has not even been voted for closure. It is on-topic but it also is poorly framed and sounds more like a personal experience. If it is about the biomolecules controlling the sleep-wake cycle then it is too broad. Overall, your examples are not justifying the title of your post.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I think answers to both of these questions could definitely fit in with neurobiology and belong here (though I also agree that neither is the greatest formulation of a question), and people are likely to get a different type of answer to them here than they would in cog-sci. As a neuroscientist myself I mostly stay away from cog sci because it is often a totally different approach to understanding - other neuroscientists would fall on the other side.